# React Native : render a fetched data structure

Tags: json, node.js, listview, react-native, render

I am new to Javascript (NodeJS & JSON data structure) and React native, and I am trying to display some datas on the iOS screen test (react native). I did my best to understand but I am stuck.

I made a GET route on my Express app at /places on localhost:3000 :

```
router.get('/places', (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Connection established to', url);

    var colPlaces = db.collection('places');

    colPlaces.find().toArray(function  (err,result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send('error!');
        } else if (result.length) {
            res.send(result);
        } else {
            res.send('No entries');
        } 
    })

    db.close();
}});
})
```

It displays a data structure on my browser (seems to be an Array of JSON objects ?)

```
[
{"_id":"5894fdd694f5d015dc0962bc","name":"The good bar","city":"London"},
{"_id":"5894fdd694f5d015dc0962bd","name":"Alpha bar","city":"Paris"}
]
```

I am then trying to render it on my native react project :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var datas = async function getDatas() { 
        try { 
            let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/places'); 
            let responseJson = await response.json(); 
            return responseJson; 
        } catch(error) { 
            console.error(error); } 
    }

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(datas())
    };
}

render() {
    return (
       <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 22}}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
}
```

But all I got is two "0" on my screen.
Can someone help me to find out what is wrong ?
What is/are,
* "result" variable structure ? seems to be an array of JS objects.
* "response" and "responseJSON" variables ?
* "datas()" and dataSource type

Should I parse something ? I am a bit confuse. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, "data" is already plural, there is no "datas". :) Now back to your question, `getData` is async function, so you cannot just call `getData()` and expect it to return data immediately. In the constructor, set dataSource to empty list, then:

```
async function getData() { 
    try { 
        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/places'); 
        return response.json(); // this call is not async
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    } 
}

componentDidMount() {
  let data = await this.getData();
  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  this.setState({dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data)});
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Finally I got this tuto to fix the problem [link](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/es7-async-await-with-react-native-35ca167cc326#.htsw4kmnu)

Isn't is a syntax error with `async function getData()` rather than àsync getData()`. Does not `componentDidMount()` need a async as well since it has a "await" methode ?